# Count percentages of random number occurance

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a distribution problem. For example: I want to call a function, and this function should trigger a second function. That second function can be one of 3 (three) options.  I want:
Function A should be called 10% of the time
Function B should be called 20% of the time
Function C should be called 70% of the time

With 2 options, (70%-30%), it is easy. I generate a random integer Math.round(Math.random()*100), then check for the result being < 30. results < 30 go to one function, the rest to the other and it balances out to 70/30.

However, I am running into a logic problem when it comes to having more than two options.

This is the outline:

```
 //Initialize variables
var twentyPercentCount = 0;
var seventyPercentCount = 0;
var tenPercentCount = 0;
//Iterate 10,000 times
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  // generate whole integer 0-99
   // logic
}
console.log("number of times value is < 20:  " + twentyPercentCount);
console.log("number of times value is < 70:  " + seventyPercentCount);
console.log("remaining ten percent range:  " + tenPercentCount);
```

What I am currently trying:

```js
var twentyPercentCount = 0;
    var seventyPercentCount = 0;
    var tenPercentCount = 0;
    var distributionArray = [10, 20, 100];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      var rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
      // find first element > the random number
      let chosenNum = distributionArray.find((element) => element >= rnd);
      if (chosenNum == 100) {
        seventyPercentCount += 1;
      } else if (chosenNum == 20) {
        twentyPercentCount += 1;
      } else {
        tenPercentCount += 1;
      }
    }
    console.log("number of values less than 10:  " + twentyPercentCount);
    console.log("number of values less than 20:  " + twentyPercentCount);
    console.log("70 percent range:  " + seventyPercentCount);
```

Results

```
**number of values less than 10:  943
number of values less than 20:  943
70 percent range:  8025**
```

The problem is that the 10 and 20 percent buckets are still equal. I know this is a logic deficiency on my part, but can't get past it.

Comment: your if/else if/else doesn't account for the numbers between your ranges.  It is only looking for 100, 20, and everything else respectively.  If you can change it to be something like if (chosenNum > 10 && chosenNum <= 20) you would get the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the sums of the wanted distributions

```
[10, 20,  70] // distribution
[10, 30, 100] // totals
```

and check against the random value.

```js
const
    distribution = [10, 20, 70],
    totals = distribution.map((s => v => s += v)(0));
    count = [0, 0, 0];

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const
      rnd = Math.random() * 100,
      chosenNum = totals.findIndex(element => rnd < element);

  count[chosenNum]++;      
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: This solution works as desired.  Can I ask some assistance in clarifying the logic of the included map function, for my own education:  
totals = distribution.map((s => v => s += v)(0));

// create new array by summing values of distribution array
// [ 10+0, 20+10, 70+20+10 ]
// OR is it:
//[ 10+0=10,20+10=30,70+30=100 ]

i am getting lost. we use (s) as temp variable for each element as we iterate through the array. then a function is called to operate on that with a new iterator (v), i am getting lost and would like to understand.
Thank you.

Comment: the concept is a closure over `s` which takes the sum of the previous summing of `v`. The last one describes the action: `[0+10=10, 10+20=30, 30+70=100]`